# Has The Watcher (Uatu) ever been mentioned or referred to in a Marvel movie or TV show

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel

Has [The Watcher (Uatu)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watcher_(comics)) ever been mentioned or referred to in a Marvel movie or TV show?

Comment: Only if you believe that Stan Lee is the Watcher and all shall be revealed in phase 15, when Fox and Disney get into bed. ;)

Comment: @Stormie Change 15 to 3 and you’re spot on. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Uatu has not made an appearance or been mentioned in any live-action movies or within the [marvel-cinematic-universe](/questions/tagged/marvel-cinematic-universe). He has, however, appeared within other Marvel TV shows including:

- The 1967 Fantastic Four animated series
- The Incredible Hulk Segment of The Marvel Super Heroes
- An episode of the X-Men animated series
- An episode of the 1994 Fantastic Four animated series
- Appearances on the Silver Surfer animated series
- Appearances on The Super Hero Squad Show
- Appeaances on Avengers Assemble (the animated TV series)
- An episode of the Hulk and the Agents of SMASH

([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uatu#Television))

There has been some misunderstanding based on some scenes in *Guardians of the Galaxy 2* where Stan Lee makes appearances alongside some unnamed Watchers, and some people believe that Lee is a Watcher, or even Uatu himself.

Producer Kevin Feige shuts that idea down in [an interview with Collider](http://collider.com/guardians-of-the-galaxy-2-after-credits-scenes-james-gunn-kevin-feige-interview/#post-credits-scenes-explained):

> *Kevin, in one of the scenes during the credits, we see The Watcher, Uatu, in there. Might Stan Lee might be The Watcher, in some way?*
>
> FEIGE: Well, I wouldn’t say you saw Uatu. I would say that you saw some Watchers. Stan Lee clearly exists above and apart from the reality of all the films, so the notion that he could be sitting there, on a cosmic pit stop, during the jump gate sequence in Guardians was something very fun.

In [an interview with ScreenRant](http://screenrant.com/guardians-galaxy-2-watchers-marvel-fox/) He further insinuates that while Marvel may use the Watchers (as a race) in the MCU, they may not have rights to use *Uatu*.

> *And that’s also a question I had, the Watchers, aren’t they Fantastic Four owned by Fox? Has there been a deal made?*
>
> No. There’s joint custody with a number of things. There are certain characters that they have, but races that we share. If that makes sense?

Comment: This leads to an interesting question: Which studio owns the watcher?

Comment: @CBredlow He first appeared in The Fantastic Four #13 (April 1963), so I quess that he belongs to the F4 franchise, like Galactus or Silversurfer.

Comment: Rights are not solely based on first appearances, otherwise Marvel couldn't have used Scarlet Witch and Quicksilver, as they first appeared in X-Men.

Comment: This answer is no longer correct... it should be updated to fix or marked as incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

As of 2021, The Watcher has now appeared in the MCU, in the animated series *[What If...?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_If...%3F_(TV_series))*. The Watcher introduces each episode's alternate scenario, and makes occasional background appearances and observational comments as each scenario progresses.

> Starting with the penultimate episode, the threat of Infinity Ultron forces the Watcher to break his oath and begin interfering with events directly, so as to prevent the annihilation of the multiverse.

This was made possible after Disney purchased Fox, re-obtaining the rights to the Fantastic Four and its supporting cast, including The Watchers.